# Selecting range without knowing number of rows or columns having data in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for code for two different types of selection.  One code would select in an L shape all of the rows in one column and all of the columns in one row.  In the example of having data in the range A1:A10, and data in row 10 only from col A - K.  The selection would look like an L. How can you do this without knowing how many rows or columns have data in them?

The second code would have the same data, but need to select the whole range A1:K10 in that example, but the code would need to select whatever range had the data.

Comment: Are you selecting the last row* and to the end of the column  or something else?

Comment: @CodyG. that was the other one i was interested in.  do u know how to do that?  the problem i run in to is most code assumes all the cells from rows 1:10 in columns B:K are populated, but only the rows in col A are and in the last row through the last column forming an L so you really have to activate the last cell to end over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer.  i have to do a union.  here is the code with the union at the end.

```
Sub mywork()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Dim rng As Range

'~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = [Sheet1]

With ws
    '~~> Get the last row and last column
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = .Cells(lRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    '~~> Set the range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

End With
Set rng = Application.Union(Range("A1:A" & lRow), rng)

rng.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`activesheet.usedrange.address` should tell you the used range.

In your case something like this should work: `[sheet1].usedrange.select` (Replaces all the code in the module)

The benefit here is the fact that you are not hard coding "A1:A" against the last identified cell, works well if you have blank rows at the top.